# Inconsistency for size_t and sizeof

Tags: c++, sizeof

Isn't it bothersome that the result of a native operator cannot be defined without including a header file?

According to this [page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t), `size_t` is defined in headers cstddef, cstdio, cstring, ctime, and cstdlib. Thus, if neither of those headers is included then `size_t` should be undefined. However, the following program compiles without any warning (using MSVC 2015RC).

```
int main()
{
    auto d_Size = sizeof( int );
    return 0;
}
```

It seems that `size_t` is somewhat of a bastard between a native type and a typedef. What does the standard say?

Comment: Yeah, good question. Actually, if you replace auto with size_t it compiles fine in VC++, but gcc gives an error

Comment: It actually depends on compiler implementation. Some compiler allows to use `size_t` without including any header files while some compilers does not.

Comment: @technorevolutionary But they shouldn't be! In current code everything is clear - sizeof returns type of std::size_t, but std::size_t is just a synonym for unsigned int, so it actually returns unsigned int and auto in this case is just unsigned int.

Comment: @DmitriSosnik it does not return `unsigned int` for sure. On my machine, it returns `unsigned long`.

Comment: @vsoftcoYeah, that's right, cause your compiler included cstddef when it's been build. So, it knows for each platform what std::size_t is. But it doesn't return std::size_t it returns type of std::size_t, so client code doesn't need to know what is std::size_t.

Comment: However, using `typeid` without proper includes causes compilation error on GCC `must #include <typeinfo> before using typeid`, which is funny.

Comment: @DmitriSosnik `cstddef` has nothing to do with the compiler. The compiler is independent of the headers. When it was built, it was decided that on X platform, the result of `sizeof` will be e.g. `unsigned long int`. Then, the conforming standard library that came with it defined `size_t` as `unsigned long int`. The need for `size_t` appears whenever you want to make sure that your type is "large" enough to store basically any possible representable size. Otherwise some code will use `unsigned int`, others `unsigned long`, and porting them will be a mess.

Comment: @DmitriSosnik and yes, I agree, clients should not care about what is the underlying type of `size_t`, if that's what you meant. Just use it transparently.

Comment: @vsoftco: That's totally wrong. With DOS, some compilers supported multiple memory models. Whether `size_t` was 16 bits or 32 bits depended on a compiler setting. `stddef` has to figure out the compiler setting, which was possible precisely because the two are very dependent.

Comment: @MSalters I didn't mean that, thanks for the comment, I put it wrong. What I meant was that first there was the compiler, and second `<cstddef>` coming with a supporting standard library designed for that compiler (and of course can be more than one version of the file, or `#ifdef` directives , for different compiler versions/settings, as you mentioned). The compiler didn't "use" `<cstddef>`, the compiler could very well have been written in pure C.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**5.3.3 Sizeof [expr.sizeof]**

> 1) The sizeof operator yields the number of bytes in the object
>   representation of its operand. The operand is either an expression,
>   which is an unevaluated operand (Clause 5), or a parenthesized
>   type-id. The sizeof operator shall not be applied to an expression
>   that has function or incomplete type, to the parenthesized name of
>   such types, or to a glvalue that designates a bit-field. sizeof(char),
>   sizeof(signed char) and sizeof(unsigned char) are 1. The result of
>   sizeof applied to any other fundamental type (3.9.1) is
>   implementation-defined. [ Note: in particular, sizeof(bool),
>   sizeof(char16_t), sizeof(char32_t), and sizeof(wchar_t) are
>   implementation-defined.75 — end note ] [ Note: See 1.7 for the
>   definition of byte and 3.9 for the definition of object
>   representation. — end note ]
>
> 6) **The result of sizeof and sizeof... is a constant of type std::size_t**.
>   [ Note: std::size_t is defined in the standard header `<cstddef>`
>   (18.2). — end note ]

However, `std::size_t` is just a type alias. The `sizeof` operator can return its result without any need of "accessing" the type alias; the result of `sizeof` is some fundamental type (implementation defined), which is then aliased as `std::size_t` in `<cstddef>`.

Note also that in C++ `typedef` or `using` **do not define a new type** (i.e. a *strong type*), but only an alias (i.e. their `typeid` are the same). Hence, in your case, `auto` just deduces the fundamental type returned by the `sizeof` operator, which is the same as the type alias `std::size_t`. No problem for the compiler.

Comment: It's even more fun with `nullptr`; at least `size_t` is an alias for some unsigned integer type you can write in another manner. +1, BTW.

Comment: @T.C. have to say that I still don't understand perfectly `nullptr`. I will once take the time to read the standard .

Answer (score 4):

According to the C++ standard, `std::size_t` is defined in `<cstddef>`.

> **5.3.3 Sizeof**
>
> ...
>
> 6 The result of `sizeof` and `sizeof...` is a constant of type `std::size_t.` [ *Note:* `std::size_t` is defined in
>   the standard header `<cstddef>` (18.2). — *end note* ]